# Best way to copy over items to a List partially?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, list, copy

Let's say you have two arrays, `src` and `dest`. `dest` is bigger. You want to copy over all the elements from `src` to the beginning of `dest` and overwrite anything that may already be there. To do this, we can do an `Array.Copy(src, dest, src.Length)`, which is both more concise and more efficient than a for loop.

Now, say `dest` becomes a `List<T>`. What's the most efficient way to copy all of the elements from `src`? I know List is internally implemented using an array, so if we could get our hands on that (barring reflection, of course) we could just do an `Array.Copy` and this would be a non-issue.

I'm not looking for a for-loop because of said reasons, but if that's the only way to do it I guess that'll have to do.

---

**Edit:** I was hoping not to have to type up a code sample on my phone, but it seems from the barrage of incorrect answers I'm going to have to:

```
int[] src = { 1, 2, 3 };
var dest = new List<int>() { 4, 5, 6, 7 };

for (int i = 0; i < src.Length; i++)
{
    dest[i] = src[i];
}
```

What I'm looking for would be the logical equivalent of the above, but have the performance of Array.Copy.

Comment: Sometimes I wish `C#` was more like [tag:fortran] where you can do `A(1:10) = B` which copies `B` into the first 10 elements of `A`.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the same result as `Array.Copy` I would use

```
var src = new int[] { 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55 };
var dest = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };

dest.RemoveRange(0, src.Length);
dest.InsertRange(0, src);

// dest: [ 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ]
```

**Edit:**
This method is about 7 times slower than `Array.Copy`, but for large Arrays much faster than to loop through the array. If you have smal source arrays, a loop may be the best choice.

Comment: Are you sure? I mean at least you understood my question, but I don't see how something 7x slower than Array.Copy can be faster than a for-loop. Last I checked, a loop is only about 20% slower than Array.Copy.

Comment: It depends on the size of the source array. It takes longer to loop through 5,000 entries in an source array, than to remove and insert the first 5,000 entries. Otherwise if you only have 5 entries in the source array it's faster to loop, because the remove/insert range methods are kind of slow.

Comment: Interesting, I just looked through the List source code and what you're saying appears to be true. If the enumerable is determined to be an array (which it is), then it will use Array.Copy is both places. +1.

Comment: Here is some code I used to play around with the different methods if you want :) [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/L3VfXhzy)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
int[] desta = (int[]) typeof(List<int>)
               .GetField("_items", BindingFlags.NonPublic |     BindingFlags.Instance)
               .GetValue(dest);
Array.Copy(src, desta, src.Length)
```

Comment: I explicitly said "barring reflection" in my post, but +1 just for understanding the question.

Comment: Go through the code of List<T> at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646 you will see that internal array is not exposed outside. So you have three options left: use loop for copy, use reflection to get internal array and then use Array.Copy, or implement your own version of List<T> by implementing interface IList<T> and expose internal array as a property.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just call `ToList()` on `src` array which will Create a `List<int>` from `int[]`. A small sample

```
        int[] src = new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,44,555,45,654};
        List<int> dest = src.ToList();
```

Comment: Nope, you need an existing List to copy to.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
int[] src = new int[] {1, 2, 3};

List<int> dest = new List<int>(src);
```

Comment: Nope, you're supposed to have an *existing* List that you copy elements from the array to.

Answer (score 0):

If your src is a list, another option is to use ForEach defined in List, I believe the performance is similar to Array.Copy

```
dest = new List<T>();
src.ForEach(item => dest.Add(item));
```

If you need value copy, you can write this:

```
src.ForEach(item => dest.Add(item.Clone()));
```

In this case, just need to make sure item is ICloneable.

Comment: This works fine when dest is an empty List, but what if I have one with elements that I want to copy to?

Answer (score 0):

Just compared your function with the Array.Copy() function.

```
//values used for the benchmark
int[] src = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] destArray = { 4, 5, 6, 7 };
var destList = new List<int>() { 4, 5, 6, 7 };

//Array.Copy() test : avarage 1004 ms
for (int i = 0; i < 20000000; i++)
{
    Array.Copy(src, destArray, src.Length);
}
//Your solution test : avarage 634 ms
for (int i = 0; i < 20000000; i++)
{
    Copy(src, destList, src.Length);
}

public void Copy(int[] sourceArray, List<int> destinationList, int length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        destinationList[i] = sourceArray[i];
    }
}
```

*these results are the avarage of 20 benchmarks.